# How to check if libwebsockets server port is already taken?

Tags: c++, c, websocket

I have an issue where two instances of libwebsockets server are trying to use the same port. The first instance is running OK but the second one is crashing when trying to execute libwebsocket_create_context(..):

```
  struct lws_context_creation_info info;
  memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));
  info.port = 9000;
  info.protocols = protocols;
  info.extensions = libwebsocket_get_internal_extensions();
  info.gid = -1;
  info.uid = -1;
  struct libwebsocket_context *context;
  context = libwebsocket_create_context(&info);
```

Is there a way to check if the desired port is already taken?

try {} catch(..) {} are not able to catch the crash.

Comment: It looks like `libwebsocket_create_context` should return `NULL` if your desired port is already in use.  If this doesn't happen for you, try debugging through `libwebsocket_context_destroy`

Comment: @simonc I've compiled a debug lib and have found that when one has an already opened libwebsocket port the lib fails on the `close(sockfd)` function at this code: `if (n < 0) {lwsl_err("ERROR on binding to port %d (%d %d)\n", info->port, n, errno); close(sockfd); goto bail; }`. Apparently it fails to close a port from the other libwebsocket instance. I dont know if it's a good idea to comment the `close(..)` function but this had solved the issue for now.

Comment: I guess I should have addressed this question to @warmcat

Comment: This sounds like a bug in libwebsocket.  If you have time, it'd be good to post a description of the problem (& proposed fix) to their [bug tracker](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/issues)

Comment: Sure! I'll post it shortly.

Comment: Yup, turned out to be a bug indeed. New version fixes the issue.